# Flutter - How to minimize Text() when the user scrolls

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

> So I have a ListView(), that starts with a Text() as a title, but I want the Text() to minimize when I scroll. But if I scroll back up it reverses the animation, just like the gif. Does anyone have an idea on how to make something like this? I'm not very skilled with controllers.

[image: gif]

Comment: You need to use Slivers. SliverAppBar, SliverList, etc etc. Head over to flutter docs!

Comment: @Abbas Thanks! [Here's what I have so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61677561/flutter-how-can-i-make-the-title-of-a-flexiblespacebar-fade)